# Expand particles.js to background

Tags: javascript, html, particles, particles.js

I bought a template and I'm modifying it to make my website, I'm a designer, and I do not have much idea of code but I want to learn and I decided to venture into making the web like this. I want to put the plugin particles.js as background, I managed to put it in the index but I have been put like this and I have no idea how to do to expand it. As if in photoshop take it from a corner and drag to occupy the whole background.

Here's the problem:
[image: Here's the problem]

And here's the particle.js div onto index.html:

```html
<div id="particles-js"
     style="background-color: #000; position: absolute; background-size: cover; background-repeat: no-repeat; background-position: 100%;">
     <canvas class="particles-js-canvas-el"
            style="width: 100%; height: 100%;" width="1617" height="708">
     </canvas>
</div>
```

It's located above scripts and below the footer.

Comment: I've used this library and think I could help you out. Could you make a Codepen to reproduce your problem?

Comment: Here's a site I made a few years ago that I think accomplishes what you're going for: http://personal.stevens.edu/~acawleye/

Comment: Thank you man for your help. I don't know how to use Codepen but I can provide you my code through this web. I just put the div code of your web on my index and now looks like this: https://i.ibb.co/CtKYkFp/Screenshot-2018-12-11-12-51-10.png Is like a block below the website instead of a background. Sorry if I sound stupid but I don't know so much about code and I only want to put the particles.js as my background and I can't. I think that is a template problem so this is the original template: https://hencework.com/theme/penelope/his/ You'll have a friend forever if you can help me haha

Comment: I'd love to help! But I'm only going to be able to if I have a way to see your entire project or a small reproduction of your problem. Unfortunately images are not much help. Take a look at Codepen, and if it's not working for you paste your HTML and CSS files here.

Comment: Thanks again Austin, you're a kind person. I've put the index.html and style.css in the only pen in my codepen profile. I don't know if it's what you need or if I should give you something else, don't hesitate to tell me and again thank you very much for offering to help me, it means a lot to me. https://codepen.io/tormius/ I can send you my local folder project via wetransfer with all the archives if you need.

Comment: It looks like you have a lot of javascript dependencies on your local computer, so, unfortunately, the Codepen will not work correctly unless you load them all through something like https://cdnjs.com. If you don't want to do that, please post a link where I can download your local project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you need is some CSS to position the `<div>`. Add this to your `<style>` tag. A good place to start when you get stuck in the future is [the W3 Schools CSS intro.](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_intro.asp) Best of luck!

```css
/* the #id of your div */
#particles-js {
    /* stay in a constant spot on the page, regardless of scroll */
    position: fixed;
    /* fill the entire page */
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    /* remove the space along the edges */ 
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    /* position it to start at the top of the page */
    top: 0;
    /* put it behind other content */
    z-index: -1;
}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much Austin! You're amazing :D I have problems with the particles.js archive, I want to edit the particles but when changing the parameters nothing happens. When opening the particles.js file in brackets I see that has many problems I do not know if it will be because of that. What do you think? Can you help with this too? It's the last thing I need. Thanks again.

Comment: You're welcome! I'd recommend you ask a new question with specific parameters you are trying to change, as well as a reproducible example. We try not to ask others to write too much code for us without sharing some code we've tried ourselves, as this is not a code writing service.